# Протокол отладчика не совместим с отлаживаемым объектом

Tags: c#, отладчик

Есть веб сервис. написан на Net 5.0. Для отладки использую Visual Studio 2022. В коде стоит вызов отладчика через Debugger.Lounch() но при переходе к отладке студия выдает ошибку:

Невозможно подключится к аварийному процессу. Протокол  отладчика несовместим с отлаживаемым объектом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить.

Comment: .NET 5 SDK установлен?

Comment: Да установлены уже все возможные

Comment: Есть у кого идеи?

Comment: Не знаю, никогда не отлаживал сборки с галочкой (pdb файл на месте?). Да и смысла в этом не очень много, достаточно хорошо настроить логирование. Исключение показывает трассировку стека.